# Force user to add Gmail account to device

Tags: android

I am using GCM in my application. But I am  trying to create a scenario were I would force the user to add is or gmail account during installation of my application so my app can function.

I this line below sufficient enough for that `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS`.

I have created an activity that is called before the activity that would use GCM. So I thinking that I should add a function which would be check if the user as added and synchronize a gmail account to his device before letting him proceed.

Please How do I achieve this.

Comment: GCM requires Google Play to be installed on the device, downloading your app off Google Play requires the user to be signed into a Google account. As far as I remember, GCM doesn't require the user to be signed into a Google account for it to work.

Comment: I am not hosting the app on the google now. that would be later. there is a possibility that some users would not have google play on their mobile device. and synchronize an account to your mobile device is different from signing in.

Comment: Is there a way you can detect if Google play is not installed on device